# trying to make some gobal variables linker command failed

Tags: c++, global-variables

this is my main file calling the function that deals with save files for my game

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "Menu.cpp"

using namespace std;

extern int level;

int main() {
    extern int level;
    MM_class MM_obj;
    MM_obj.MM_func();
    cout << level;
}
```

i want to have the information that my MM_class gets to be global so i dont have to call alot of functions, this is MM_class:

```
#include "Menu.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int level, weapon, secondWeapon;
int itemslot1, itemslot2;

class MM_class{
public:

void MM_func() {
    string saveName, saveInfo;
    int rechoice = 1;

    char gamename[] = "TBA";

    cout << "Welcome to " << gamename << "\n\nDo you want to load an old save or a new save?\n\n1 = new save      2 = old save\n\n";

    int saveChoice;
    cin >> saveChoice;

    if (saveChoice == 1) {
        ofstream file;
        cout << "what would you like to name the new file? (one word please)\n\n";
        cin >> saveName;
        file.open(saveName);
        file << "11100";
        level, weapon, secondWeapon = 1;
        itemslot1, itemslot2 = 0;
        file.close();
    }
    else {
        if (saveChoice == 2) {
            while (rechoice == 1) {
            ifstream file;
            cout << "please enter the save name\n\n";
            cin >> saveName;
            file.open(saveName);
            if  (file.is_open()) {
                cout << "save successfully opened!\n";
                int getInfo = 0;
                int saveInfo[5];
                extern int level, weapon, secondWeapon;
                extern int itemslot1, itemslot2;
                while (getInfo != 4) {
                    file >> saveInfo[getInfo];
                    getInfo++;
                }
                level = saveInfo[0];
                weapon = saveInfo[1];
                secondWeapon = saveInfo[2];
                itemslot1 = saveInfo[3];
                itemslot2 = saveInfo[4];
                rechoice = 0;
                file.close();
            }
            else {
                if (!file.is_open()) {
                    cout << "file could not be opened... \n\nattempt to open a different save file?\n\n";
                    cin >> rechoice;
                    file.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
};
```

it makes a new text file, or save file when chosen so, but it reads one, too if chosen so, so i want my variables: level, weapon, secondWeapon, itemslot1 and itemslot2 to be accessible to the entire program, and editable so that if a player levels up, it can change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining some global objects in your header file (`level`, `weapon`, etc.). This breaks the one definition rule. Any `.cpp` file that includes this header will have its own definitions of those variables.

The appropriate way to deal with this is to *declare* the objects in the header file using `extern`, and then provide definitions in a single `.cpp` file. That is, your header should contain:

```
extern int level, weapon, secondWeapon;
extern int itemslot1, itemslot2;
```

And then you would have this in a single `.cpp` file:

```
int level, weapon, secondWeapon;
int itemslot1, itemslot2;
```

Comment: then would these values carry out through out my program

Comment: @Bob_the_rhino Yep. Any file that includes the header will be able to see them.